# How to hide Actions button in Sales Order screen

Tags: acumatica

Can some help me to hide Actions button in Sales Order screen for Transfer Order type, please suggest.

Comment: you could just use the UI and modify the automation steps to control the display of actions - no need for code. As for code you just need to use the action to SetEnabled()

Comment: Or to hide the Action use SetVisible()

Answer (score 0):

You can use following line of code to hide button pOSupplyOK, which has title PO Link:

```
Base.Actions["pOSupplyOK"].SetVisible(false);
```

You can find necessary value of string via looking into source code like this:

[image]
Acumatica creates array of each button, and indexes it by string name of action.

Comment: Should also be able to use the action name if the action is declared on the Base graph. Ex: Base.pOSupplyOK.SetVisible(false);

Answer (score 0):

you can put it on the `DAC_RowSelected` event and make the buttons not visible by using

if(`row.DocumentType`?(I can't remember the field) == TransferOrderType) //just a pseudocode.

{
Base.ButtonVariableNameHere.SetVisible(false);}